# Amazon or priceline credit card payment system implementation

Tags: amazon-web-services, payment, credit-card, gateway

This is the scenario I expect the system behave:

> I have a platform where users can register and store their credit card information online, and with specific user's action, system automatically settles payment.
>   Of course, user expect automatic payment system as we said so when they enter their card information, and the purpose of this is to simplify the process when they decided to pay for something.

My question is this:

I found that Amazon saves user's card information when they purchased some products then user doesn't need to put all the card information again but just select from the list of cards he used and with one click, it finishes payment.
Also, in price line, I found that it automatically settles after bid accepted.

So I tried to find the provider or payment gateway company that Priceline or Amazon provide, and tried to find the way to implement the system at least, but couldn't find any. What I have found so far were like, using paypal, and it requires user to have paypal id

I'm doing this in PHP, can anybody give me some clue please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with most payment gateways that support recurring payments.

Typically what you would do for new customers is capture their card details 'as normal' (via the payment gateway). The payment gateway will return a token id which you then store against the customer record

Next time that customer makes a payment you can submit the *tokenised* card number to the payment gateway

Since you mentioned Amazon, you might want to look at their payment service API: http://aws.amazon.com/fps/

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Here's what I'm curious about; 
does user need to login to Amazon or payment gateway first? to proceed payment?

Comment: I am currently testing on Cyber Source, hoping this can be the answer